# How do I pass a 'general' priority_queue as function argument in c++

Tags: c++, templates

In my `main` function, I have a bunch of `priority_queues` all of them have `int` in them, but some have `less<int>`, others have `greater<int>`:

```
//std:: removed for clarity
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int>> pq1;
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq2;
```

I wish to make a function that accepts two `priority_queue` by reference and pops the first and puts into the second.

But, this gives me an error:

```
void f(priority_queue<int> &from, priority_queue<int> &to) {
    int x = from.top();
    from.pop();
    to.push(x);
}
```

When passing my priority_queues into the function, it gives me an error. (no matching function for call)

How can I fix this without making four separate functions for 'greater' and 'less' combinations?

Comment: What version of C++ do you use, the answer can depend :  concepts (C++20) or constexpr template functions (C++17) or metatemplate programming (before C++17).
The basic idea is template f with to template arguments. Then check if the argument types implement `from.top`, `from.pop`, `to.push`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a function template:

```
template<class C1, class L1, class C2, class L2>
void f(std::priority_queue<int, C1, L1> &from, std::priority_queue<int, C2, L2> &to) {
    int x = from.top();
    from.pop();
    to.push(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change the function as described in [fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76339075/7582247) but instead of requiring that the target of the extraction is another `priority_queue` you could make it more generic by creating a function template that simply returns the extracted value.

```cpp
template<class C>
auto extract_top(C& c) {
    struct popper {
        ~popper() {
            c.pop();
        }
        C& c;
    };
    popper p{c};
    return std::move(c.top());
}
```

You could then put the extracted value in another `priority_queue` or store it anywhere you'd like:

```cpp
pq2.emplace(extract_top(pq1));
```